# How to handle exceptions with Pyramid transaction manager?

Tags: python, exception, transactions, pyramid

I'm building my first Pyramid app (coming from Pylons) and I'm trying to figure out how to handle exceptions with pyramid_tm... For example, in Pylons I would do something like

```
try:
   Session.add(object)
   Session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
   Session.rollback()
   flash("Object already present")
```

but how is this supposed to be done with pyramid_tm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Session.flush()` instead of `Session.commit()`.

With pyramid_tm, you should never (need to) do `commit()` yourself in request handling code.

Comment: This totally solved my problem. But it's still not clear where I find this, e.g., in the Pyramid docs. It seems like the Pyramid docs should have this (or at least a pointer) since the default scaffold combines straight sqlalchemy with zope.sqlalchemy - leaving a beginning user a bit unsure on how to navigate!